# How to get data in specific format using scala?

Tags: json, scala, scala-collections, playframework-json

I have a raw json in following format-

```
"luns": [
{
  "numReadBlocks": 15444876,
  "numWriteBlocks": 13530714,
  "blockSizeInBytes": 512,
  "writeIops": 495344,
  "readIops": 312702,
  "serialNumber": "aaaaaaa",
  "uuid": "id",
  "shareState": "none",
  "usedBytes": 6721716224,
  "totalSizeBytes": 16106127360,
  "path": "/vol/lun_23052014_025830_vol/lun_23052014_025830"
},
{
  "numReadBlocks": 15444876,
  "numWriteBlocks": 13530714,
  "blockSizeInBytes": 512,
  "writeIops": 495344,
  "readIops": 312702,
  "serialNumber": "aaaaaaa",
  "uuid": "id",
  "shareState": "none",
  "usedBytes": 6721716224,
  "totalSizeBytes": 16106127360,
  "path": "/vol/lun_23052014_025830_vol/lun_23052014_025830"
 }]
```

The luns may contains list.
I want to process above json and form output as following-

```
"topStorageLuns": [
{
    "name": "Free (in GB)",
    "data": [7.79,7.79]
},
{
    "name": "Used (in GB)",
    "data": [7.21,7.21]
}]
```

I tried following in order to get output-

```
val storageLuns = myRawJson
val topStorageLuns = storageLuns.map { storageLun =>
    val totalLunsSizeOnStorageDevice = storageLun.luns.foldLeft(0.0) {
      case (totalBytesOnDevice, lun) =>
        totalBytesOnDevice + lun.usedBytes.getOrElse(0.0).toString.toLong
    }
    val totalAvailableLunsOnStorageDevice = storageLun.luns.foldLeft(0.0) {
      case (totalBytesOnDevice, lun) =>
        totalBytesOnDevice + lun.usedBytes.getOrElse(0.0).toString.toLong
    }

    Json.obj("name" -> storageLun.hostId, "data" -> "%.2f".format(totalLunsSizeOnStorageDevice / (1024 * 1024 * 1024)).toDouble)
  }
```

Can anybody help me to get desired output please???

Comment: It's not really clear where the numbers in your expected output are supposed to come from, based on your input.

Comment: actually numbers (usedBytes) are converted to GB and assigned to 'y'

Answer (score 2):

The key lesson I want to impart is that your algorithm should reflect the shape of the output you want. Work backward from the result you want to build the algorithm.

It looks to me like you want to create an array of length 2, where each entry has a corresponding algorithm (spaced used, space free). Within each of these elements, you want a nested array with an element for each item in your input array, calculated using the algorithm from the outer array. Here's how I would approach the problem:

1) Define your algorithms

```
  val dfAlgorithm: (Seq[(String, JsValue)] => Double) = _.foldLeft(0.0) { (acc, item) =>
    /* whatever logic you need to do */
  }

  val duAlgorithm: (Seq[(String, JsValue)] => Double) = _.foldLeft(0.0) { (acc, item) =>
    /* whatever logic you need to do */
  }
```

2) Create a data structure to map over to build your final output

```
  val stats = Seq("Free (in GB)" -> dfAlgorithm, "Used (in GB)" -> duAlgorithm)
```

3) Map over your input data within your mapping over your algorithms (the logic here reflects the shape of the result you want)

```
  stats.map { case (name, algorithm) =>
    Json.obj("name" -> name, "data" -> storageLuns.map { storageLun => algorithm(storageLun) }
  }
```

This isn't going to be a turnkey solution, since I don't know how your free/used algorithms are supposed to work, but this overall scheme should get you there.